# Add Controller/View menu not shown in MVC 5 project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, menu, controller

Recently I have faced problem in my MVC 5 project. When I right click on controller folder and select Add option from menu then **Controller** option is missing. Menu's were in the past, but don't know why menu is not showing now.

What could be the cause of this.

Comment: What version of VS? And can you take a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Later I found that reference added in my project for **system.web.mvc.dll** is for **version 4.0.0.** When I remove this dll and add reference of **system.web.mvc.dll** of **verion 5.2.2.0** that solved my problem.

Now menu start appearing on right click
System.Web.MVC.dll for MVC 5 can be found at the path "**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Stack 5\Packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.2.2\lib\net45**"

Comment: There were errors with your answer. This worked for me: I downloaded Mvc v5.2.7 from nuget package manager and then followed the instructions at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/releases/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2